# transforming a partial differential equation into an automous equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a system of two partial differential equations that I'm asked to solve and do the Steady-State Stability Analysis. unfortunately i need to turn it first into an **autonomous linear** system, so if anyone could help i'd be thankful

$\frac{dF(\theta)}{d\theta} = -d_{u}k^2F(\theta) + \alpha(\mu+1)^2\frac{k^2}{\theta^2G(\theta)}$

$ \frac{dG(\theta)}{d\theta} = -k^2G(\theta) + \frac{2\mu}{(\mu+1)^2}F(\theta) $

there is an alternate method to solve it in the original article that can be found here https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs002850050153 but since we didn't studied it that way i can't use it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: [Repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3662198/418542) of the same question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will do a toy problem.

Assume we have the system
\begin{align}
\frac{dX}{dt} =&\ A(t) X+B(t)Y\\
\frac{dY}{dt} =&\ C(t) X + D(t)Y
\end{align}
which is clearly not autonomous since the coefficients depends explicitly on time $t$.

To make it autonomous, you have to augment the system of equations. Define $T(t) = t$. Then we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{dT}{dt}= 1
\end{align} 
and the above system becomes
\begin{align}
\frac{dX}{dt} =&\ A(T) X+B(T)Y\\
\frac{dY}{dt} =&\ C(T) X + D(T)Y.
\end{align}

Hence we now have the autonomous system
\begin{align}
\frac{dX}{dt} =&\ A(T) X+B(T)Y\\
\frac{dY}{dt} =&\ C(T) X + D(T)Y\\
\frac{dT}{dt} =&\ 1
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have actually posted a picture of my problem with the question in the link " the system I have " can you please apply this method to it,

Comment: I saw it. But I will leave it to you.

Comment: the problem is i know how to do it that way but i want to keep my system linear, is there anyway to do it?